# Is there any difference between int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and int main(int argc, char** argv)

Tags: c, arguments, program-entry-point

Is there any difference between `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and `int main(int argc, char** argv)`
I don't see any difference.
And, which is better to use?

Comment: `char* argv[]` and `char **argv` are equivalent. However, the `char** argv[]` you have in your question is not. The choice between the two first ones is arbitrary. I like the brackets because it feels more array-like.

Comment: As the startup code does not know which one you are using, the result must be identical with both variants. Therefore you can just pick the one you like most.

Comment: Technically none. The first (`char *argv[]`) is old convention, and might be considered semantically more accurate since `argv` is an array of pointers.

Comment: Typo fixed, I always use `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`, and that's why I have made that typo.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `char **argv` because I think the automatic adjustment of `type[]` to `type*` (for some type `type`) in function parameters leads to confusion for beginners.

Comment: This isn't even a case where `main` is special. `void f(int a[])` is just a "fancy" way of writing `void f(int *a)`

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Re "*`argv` is an array of pointers.*", No, it isn't. It's a pointer to one. `sizeof(argv)` will return the size of a pointer, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

.  They have identical meaning.  I personally prefer the former, as I think it more clearly conveys the significance of the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. I prefer the one with the array declaration since it makes it more clear that it is an array of strings.

Comment: No, `argv` isn't an array of strings. It's a pointer to one. `sizeof(argv)` will return the size of a pointer, for example.

Comment: Array of strings in the C sense.

Comment: It is not an array of strings in the C sense.  It is not a C array at all.  It is a C pointer.

Comment: @Gerhard, No, `argv` is not an array of any kind. It is a pointer. You made the same mistake as Alex C. /// And "string" is a short hand for "pointer to or array of NUL-terminated sequence of chars". You corrected something that wasn't wrong. /// I didn't say what you claimed I said at all.

Comment: @Gerhard , Re "*`argv[argc]` is a null pointer*", Correct. ///  Re "*each `argv[n]` will be a pointer to a string.*", Yes, but it's also correct to just say string. /// Re "*argv is the character pointer array*", Incorrect. `argv` is a pointer to the first element of that array.

Comment: @Gerhard, [Proof](https://pastebin.com/6UD92244). You can also prove it by adding `++argv;`. Adding `++array;` would cause the program to fail to compile. But the program still compiles successfully if you add `++pointer;` or `++argv;`.

Comment: @Gerhard, Pointers and arrays are different things. 1) Arrays degrade into pointers to their first element when used as a pointer. So `a == &( a[0] )` will always be true (if `a` is an array). Furthermore, the address of an array is the address of its first element, so `&a == &( a[0] )` is always true. This also means that `a == &a` is always true. 2) You can't assign to an array (which is why `++array;` would fail to compiled in the earlier example), but you can obviously assign to a pointer. (Obviously, you can assign to elements of an array.)

Comment: Finally, 3) Function parameters can't be arrays. `void foo(char x[5]); void bar(char x[]);` means `void foo(char *x); void bar(char *x);`. Arrays used as the argument for parameters will degrade into a pointer as mentioned above. This is why `argv` can't possibly be an array.

Comment: @Gerhard, [Remember](https://stackoverflow.com/q/381542/589924) that `argv[n]` simply a pretty version of `*( argv + n )`. So `argv[n]` works with both arrays and pointers to (elements of) arrays.

Comment: @ikegami suppose we need to cleanup some comments.

Answer (score 0):

Both the syntax are same . you can choose any of syntax.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

first one is more clear and understandable for beginners.

Comment: `int b;` and `char x`; also use the same syntax. The fact that they use the same syntax doesn't mean they are interchangeable as you claim. (They do happen to be interchangeable, just not for the reason you claim.)

Comment: @ikegami I have not say that you can replace the int with char. int type variable consumes 4 bytes and char consumes 2 bytes.

Comment: No, but you did say two things were equivalent because they use the same syntax, which is clearly an invalid argument. You should replace "*Both the syntax are same . you can choose any of syntax.*" with "*Both of the following are equivalent. You can use either one.*"

Comment: I am talking in terms of its memory representation and accessing.

Comment: That may have been what you meant, but that's not what you said. If I may be blunt, what you said doesn't make sense, really. (For starters, you said they were the same syntax in the first sentence, and you said they were different syntax in the second.) I proposed a rewording in my previous comment.

Comment: @ikegami correct.